# How to optimize jquery animate performance issue

Tags: jquery, performance

I want to simulate an equalizer using 40 divs by animating their heights randomly. I get the following message but I have no idea how to optimize a large number of jquery animate?

> [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 50ms
>
> [Violation] 'setInterval' handler took 50ms

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    animateBars()
  }, 500);
})

function animateBars() {
  $(".AudioBar").each(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
      height: Math.random() * 100 + 20
    }, 800, "linear");
  })
}
```

Comment: The issue is because the calculation you're making is taking too long. There may be ways to improve the logic, or offload some of the processing to CSS. We can't really help you optimise it without seeing a working example, though. One thing I can tell you which isn't helping is that you're telling the animation to take 800ms, yet the setInterval repeats every 500ms

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I wanted to point out the 500/800ms thing, but he stops the animation. But the big deal is IMO so many animations running in parallel, instead of being aggregated in some central loop that manages them.

Comment: @TomášZato he does, but if you make the animation run for less time than the interval then you can get rid of the unecessary `stop()` call and regain some performance there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [tldr codepen](https://codepen.io/MXXIV/pen/VwZyXdK)

One performance issue may be that you're running the animations in parallel. Multiple separate running intervals are always less fast than one interval that does multiple things in one go.

When looking for performance, your best bet may be to drop the `.animate`, since you cannot improve it's performance, and roll your own code.

Gist of my suggestion:

- Use CSS animation instead of javascript, it's less work and probably faster
- Use height in `%` so that you don't need to change javascript if the height of your panel changes
- Use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval` for graphic effects

This is my implementation of your audio bars CSS style:

```
.bars {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #111;
  height: 30pt;
  display: flex;
}
.AudioBar {
  background-color: #55ff44;
  width: 5pt;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  align-self: flex-end;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

The code to alter their heights than needs to run only once in a while. It's smart to use `requestAnimationFrame` for these things, so they only run when user is watching the webpage:

```
// How many frames before changing heights
// It should be less than animation
// duration [ms] divided by 16.66
const FRAMESKIP = 25;
// Main animate function
function animateBars(framesToSkip=0) {
  // If last animation was too soon, skip this frame
  if(framesToSkip>0) {
    requestAnimationFrame(()=>{animateBars(framesToSkip-1)});
  }
  else {
    // get the audio bars for animation
    const bars = document.querySelectorAll(".AudioBar");
    // Loop over bars. Note that HTML collections are not 
    // iterable, so I'm using my little helper function
    // that's defined below
    for(const bar of toIterable(bars)) {
      // bar height (0% - 100%)
      bar.style.height = (Math.random()*100)+"%";
    }
    // Skip several frames then animate again
    requestAnimationFrame(()=>{animateBars(FRAMESKIP)});
  }
}
animateBars(0);

/**
 * Converts array-ish object to iterable.
 * This works with any object that follows these rules:
 *
 *  - `object` has a property `length` which is a positive integer or zero
 *  - for each integer `i` between 0 and `object.length`, there exists a property `object[i]`
 * @template T
 * @param {T[]|HTMLCollectionOf<T>|NodeListOf<T>|{length:number, [name:string]:T}} object
 * @returns {IterableIterator<T>}
 */
function* toIterable(object) {
    const l = object.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
        yield object[i];
    }
}
```

## Demo:

```js
// How many frames before changing heights
// It should be less than animation
// duration [ms] divided by 16.66
const FRAMESKIP = 25;
// Main animate function
function animateBars(framesToSkip=0) {
  // If last animation was too soon, skip this frame
  if(framesToSkip>0) {
    requestAnimationFrame(()=>{animateBars(framesToSkip-1)});
  }
  else {
    // get the audio bars for animation
    const bars = document.querySelectorAll(".AudioBar");
    // Loop over bars. Note that HTML collections are not 
    // iterable, so I'm using my little helper function
    // that's defined below
    for(const bar of toIterable(bars)) {
      // bar height (0% - 100%)
      bar.style.height = (Math.random()*100)+"%";
    }
    // Skip several frames then animate again
    requestAnimationFrame(()=>{animateBars(FRAMESKIP)});
  }
}
animateBars(0);

/**
 * Converts array-ish object to iterable.
 * This works with any object that follows these rules:
 *
 *  - `object` has a property `length` which is a positive integer or zero
 *  - for each integer `i` between 0 and `object.length`, there exists a property `object[i]`
 * @template T
 * @param {T[]|HTMLCollectionOf<T>|NodeListOf<T>|{length:number, [name:string]:T}} object
 * @returns {IterableIterator<T>}
 */
function* toIterable(object) {
    const l = object.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
        yield object[i];
    }
}
```

```css
.bars {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #111;
  height: 30pt;
  display: flex;
}
.AudioBar {
  background-color: #55ff44;
  width: 5pt;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  align-self: flex-end;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="bars">
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
  <div class="AudioBar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

*Not an answer to your actual question, but a bit more than a comment:*

I suggest you drop the jquery animate and instead use css's `transition: height 0.2s; transition-timing-function: linear;` and use JS just to set the height via a simple native css change:

```
$(".AudioBar").each(function() {
    this.style.height = (Math.random() * 100 + 20) + 'px';
})
```

That'll be a lot more stable and use less resource.